# Does not have BatchGetImage permission - While deploying model in sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3, deployment, amazon-sagemaker

**I am Able to train my modelusing Sagemaker TensorFlow container.**

**Below is the code:**

```
model_dir = '/opt/ml/model'
train_instance_type = 'ml.c4.xlarge'
hyperparameters = {'epochs': 10, 'batch_size': 256, 'learning_rate': 0.001}

script_mode_estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point='model.py',
    train_instance_type=train_instance_type,
    train_instance_count=1,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
    role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
    base_job_name='tf-fashion-mnist',
    framework_version='1.12.0',
    py_version='py3',
    output_path='s3://my_bucket/testing',
    script_mode=True
)
```

**Model Fitting:**

```
script_mode_estimator.fit(inputs)
```

**But when i ama trying to deploy model i ama getting this below error:**

**Deploy code is:**

```
script_mode_d=script_mode_estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                 instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge")
```

**Error is:**

UnexpectedStatusException: Error hosting endpoint tf-fashion-mnist-2020-09-23-09-05-25-791: Failed. Reason:  The role 'xyz' does not have BatchGetImage permission for the image: '520713654638.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving:1.12-cpu'.

**Please help me to resolve this issue.**

Comment: Have to go to IAM console, locate role `xyz` and add `BatchGetImage` permission to it.

Comment: Hi @Marcin Thank you for your reply, after granting the permission it is below error.              **Please make sure all images included in the model for the production variant AllTraffic exist, and that the execution role used to create the model has permissions to access them.**

Comment: This seems like a new issue. You could accept @Theo answer, and make new question with relevant new details for the new problem.

Comment: @Marcin, i have posted this issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238027/deployment-error-reason-please-make-sure-all-images-included-in-the-model-fo

Answer (score 4):

> Reason: The role 'xyz' does not have BatchGetImage permission for the image: '520713654638.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving:1.12-cpu'.

This error means that the IAM role "xyz" (you can find this in the IAM console) does not have permission to make the `BatchGetImage` API call in ECR (Elastic Container Registry, you can find this service in the ECS console).

You can find a number of example IAM policies you can use for the "xyz" role to grant it permission to perform the API call her: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policy-examples.html

To add a policy go to the IAM console, look for the "xyz" role, and either add an (inline) policy, or edit one of its existing policies (if it already has a policy that grants similar permissions it would make sense to add this permission in that policy).

Comment: Hi @Theo thanks for replying. we gave the batch get permission, so after re trying the deployment getting the this error :                                                                                
**Please make sure all images included in the model for the production variant AllTraffic exist, and that the execution role used to create the model has permissions to access them**

Comment: Hi I've added `BatchGetImage` permission to my sagemaker role but it's still complaining, could you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65004515/sagemaker-client-create-endpoint-error-does-not-have-batchgetimage-permission

Comment: @ReshmaLadakhan Hey which permission did you attach? Could you share the json policy here please?

Comment: remember that ECR and ECS need to be spelled out in the search panel for services in IAM. I was looking up ECR and ECS and didn't find anything but found when I spelled it out lol

Answer (score 1):

Instead of managing permissions by crafting a permission policy, you can use the AWS-managed AmazonSageMakerFullAccess permission policy, which allows for any actions you might want to perform in SageMaker (including `BatchGetImage`).

To do so:

1. Log onto the console -> IAM -> Roles -> Create Role
2. Create a service-linked role with sagemaker.amazonaws.com
3. Give the role `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess`
4. Give the role `AmazonS3FullAccess`

Answer (score 1):

There is a race condition where this error occurs when the IAM role has just been created, even if it includes `BatchGetImage`.
This is especially apparent if you're using CDK or the like. Introduce a one-minute delay and the call will work.

Comment: This was the relevant hint for me, thanks! Had to move the sagemaker execution role into a separate stack from the model creation.