# Deployment Error (Reason) : Please make sure all images included in the model for the production variant AllTraffic exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3, deployment, amazon-sagemaker

**I am Able to train my modelusing Sagemaker TensorFlow container.**

**Below is the code**

```
model_dir = '/opt/ml/model'
train_instance_type = 'ml.c4.xlarge'
hyperparameters = {'epochs': 10, 'batch_size': 256, 'learning_rate': 0.001}

script_mode_estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point='model.py',
    train_instance_type=train_instance_type,
    train_instance_count=1,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
    role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
    base_job_name='tf-fashion-mnist',
    framework_version='1.12.0',
    py_version='py3',
    output_path='s3://my_bucket/testing',
    script_mode=True
)
```

**Model Fitting**

```
script_mode_estimator.fit(inputs)
```

**But when i am trying to deploy model, am getting this below error**

**Deploy code is**

```
script_mode_d=script_mode_estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                 instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge")
```

**Error Message is**

UnexpectedStatusException: Error hosting endpoint tf-fashion-mnist-2020-09-29-11-13-47-493: Failed. Reason:  Please make sure all images included in the model for the production variant AllTraffic exist, and that the execution role used to create the model has permissions to access them..

**Please help me to resolve this issue.**

Comment: Hi just wondering if you have fixed this error? I've got the same error